# Why do header files ensure C programs' modularity?

Tags: c, compiler-construction, header-files, modularity

i get confused when C books and papers talk about exposing interface (.h files) and hiding implementation.e.g when C Main program will wants access to data structure like queue, it will include `queue.h` to its source. then they will talk about `queue.c` being hidden from main program i.e main has no access to concrete queue types.

Now the question: What do they mean by implementation is  **hidden from** main program and only accesses it through defined interface by header files

```
main program
------------
//call a function from .h file
Afunction();

function.h
----------
// prototypes
void Afunction(void) 

 function.c
 ---------
 // concrete implementation 
void Afunction(void) {
   // your statements here..
    {
```

I'm looking for answers even spanning compiler design if that will clear things for me.Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C doesn't do a great job of hiding implementation details. You can't hide the structure of datatypes unless you are prepared to only export them as pointers. Still, that can go a long way.

Consider the standard `FILE` datatype. The implementation of a `FILE` will need to have a lot of details, including whatever the operating system requires to associate the object with an actual datastream, the current buffer and buffer location, the EOF and error flags, and a bunch of other things I can't think of right now, because I don't need to know.

Although I use `FILE`s everyday, I don't need to think of any of those things. I just use `FILE*` in ways provided by the I/O library, and don't worry about how the details are implemented. Even if I wanted to, I can't take out my monkey wrench and modify the internal data members. Which is good, because I would almost certainly get it wrong if I tried.

The division of programs into separate compilation units also means that I don't need to know anything about the internal functions used by the I/O library to implement its external API. Undoubtedly, it uses a host of internal functions, each of them with a name. If these names were visible to my code, I would have to make sure that I didn't use them for my own purposes by accident. Fortunately, I don't have to worry about that (mostly) because the names are (mostly) hidden.

Comment: thats a bit clear explanation sir. one question, where is the code data for these (external) objects stored in memory. am tempted to think of text segment of the program address space

Comment: @cholthi: the details vary, but they are all in the same address space. If a module gives me the address of a static function, I can call the function. But modularity is not about security. It's about my being able to write my program without having to worry about internal details of the libraries. I don't need to maintain their invariants, and I don't need to worry about what I name my functions and data types.

Comment: you're very clear now. I didn't know what modularity is all about and that there is no concept of variables in the compiled code

Answer (score 2):

One of the important things we have learnt in programming, and in engineering in general, and perhaps in any human endeavour, is that it is easier to solve a problem if you first split it into smaller problems, and then solve each of those problems separately. It is, after all, easier to jump one foot high ten times, than it is to jump ten feet up in one leap.

But for this type of modularity to work as hoped for, those smaller problems need to be independent of each other, so you really can solve each of them without at the same time having to think of all the others. If you want to design a car, and split it into engine, transmission and steering, you want to be able to design the transmission as much as possible without caring about the steering, and the steering without thinking about the transmission. Otherwise, it's still one big problem, and not several smaller ones. The details of how you have implemented the transmission have to be hidden from the steering, so to speak.

As an example from C, think of the `printf` function, which you probably have called from your programs lots of times. You `#include` the header file `stdio.h`, which contains a *declaration* of `printf`, looking something like this:

```
extern int printf (const char *format, ...);
```

But there is also a *definition* of `printf`, in a `.c` file that is part of the C standard library. The definition contains the actual code that interprets format specifiers such as `%10.4f`, and prints things to the standard output. It might or might not be present on your computer in source form, but the compiled form is used whenever your program calls `printf`.

Now, have you ever had to worry about the internal details of `printf`? Probably not, and that is a good thing. It is hidden from you, not because it is secret or copyrighted, but so you don't have to worry about it.

Comment: @ThomasPadronMcCarthy you use `printf` as an example, you say the implementation file (.c) is hidden but don't explain how it is hidden. I want to understand it from memory access point of view

Comment: @CholthiPaulTtiopic: From a memory access point of view, everything in the program is (on typical modern computers) linked into the same address space, so there is no "hiding" going on on that level. "Hidden" only means that to use `printf` in your program you don't _have_ to look at the internals of the implementation, and doing so might even be a bit difficult, especially if the implementors haven't provided the source code.